# Combining date , month , year columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: dd-mm-yyyy format]

DD(10)-MM(05)-YYYY(2013)

I have a table with `DATE`, `MONTH`, `YEAR` in separate columns. How I can combine them into a single column `Created date`?

Output must be:   10-05-2013 (`DD-MM-YYYY` format)

Comment: Why have you tagged this for Oracle but have SQL Server in the title?

Comment: Storing these values as separate columns just invites invalid entries, unless you manage to write a check constraint that gets the leap year rules right. Why not store a single `datetime` (or equivalent) column from the outset?

Comment: @Joe If my answer or any other answer has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted so it may help future people searching for the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + DAY, 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + MONTH, 2) + '-' + YEAR AS Date 
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: This is what I need . Thanks for all your support and timely help

Comment: SELECT RIGHT('00' + DAY, 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + MONTH, 2) + '-' + RIGHT('0000' + YEAR, 4)  AS Date 
FROM YourTable ;

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want have a `date` field instead of a string. So use [TO_DATE()](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function. You can format `date` anyway you want later.

```
TO_DATE(YEAR + '/' + MONTH + '/' + DATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily:

```
SELECT to_char(TO_DATE('10 01 2014', 'DD MM YYYY'),'dd-mm-yyyy') AS MYDATE FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate columns you just need to use "+" in your select statement

`SELECT DATE + '-'+ MONTH + '-'+ YEAR FROM table`

Comment: Not sure if it matters for his needs, but this would technically produce 1-04-2013 for one of his rows which isn't DD-MM-YYYY